# Positive constant scalar definition

Tags: definition, constants

In French when we say "$k$ est une constante positive", that means $k\geq 0$. But I remarked that using the same sentence in English, "$k$ is a positive constant", means that $k>0$. Can one explain to me why$ k$ is a positive constant scalar doesn't include $0$?

Comment: Similar discrepancy with increasing, decreasing. Maybe that's by chauvinism, but I find it very annoying (and actually logically wrong, while nonnegative and nonpositive are correct) to say "nonincreasing" of "nondecreasing" all the time, as most theorems only require such assumptions, and not "decreasing" or "increasing".

Comment: Surprisingly, the english terminologies in these matters are not really consistent. For instance: one says convex, and strictly convex. And (hopefully...) not nonconcave and convex.

Comment: Last but not least, people from Quebec have decided to translate directly the english terminology. So "positif" in Quebec means "strictement positif" in France...

Answer (score 1):

Because the working convention is that "positive" is not the same as "not negative".

(There are other discrepancies between countries about terminology, which later were spread through the rest of the world.)

Comment: It looks like in French, "positif" is also not the same as not "négatif", because the number zero is _both_ "positif" and "négatif". From [http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nombre_negatif](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nombre_negatif): _zéro est donc un nombre (le seul) à la fois positif et négatif._

Comment: @Jeppe: If positif means "nonnegative" it makes sense that "negatif" would mean "nonpositive" in which case it is obvious that $0$ is both.

Comment: so you mean that in english : k is nonnegative which means k>=0 is the right translation to the french expression

Comment: @fidel: Exactly. Also see my comment to Jeppe above yours.

Comment: ok friend thanks

Comment: i now undrstand  , strictement positive(french)==positive(english), positive (french)=nonnegative (english) , thanks for all you friends and so sorry for troubling you

Comment: Oh, dear! If we have language barriers with something so really elementarily and ridiculously easy, imagine with some advanced stuff...I propose we all pass on to use spanish as mathematics' language...this is, mexican spanish and more specifically: central Mexico language, as northern and southern Mexico spanish has pretty cuckoo terms (...and happy April 1st to you all, too!)

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised the terminology is different in French, but [Wikipédia seems to agree](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nombre_positif):

> Un **nombre positif** est un nombre qui est supérieur (au sens de : supérieur ou égal)
>   à zéro [...] Zéro est un nombre réel positif [...]
>   Lorsqu'un nombre est positif et non nul, il est dit **strictement positif**.

The most common usage in English is that zero is neither positive nor negative. That is "positive" is normally understood to be "strictly positive". In the same way, "greater than" is normally understood to mean "strictly greater than", as in $k>j$ (not $k\ge j$).

Comment: i understand you friend, in french when k>0 we say (strictement positive) but in english they don't mention the word strictly

Answer (score 0):

This is just a matter of definition. I don't think that such conventions exist in general. Everyone uses a different definition, depending on his own preferences. So you should just take it as it is.